# How to make the Ball touch ONLY the surface of the Box?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a game where you need to catch balls in a box. And I had the following problem: I want to make the counter count the hit ONLY in the hole of the box (I drew this hit zone with a red marker).

But it turned out that the counter counted the touch of the ball with the box anywhere, and I don't need it that way. I want to make the counter count only getting into the hole of the box (so that it is logical).

A piece of code:

```
# Class for objects
class GameObjects(sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, img, x, y, width, height, speed):
        sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = transform.scale(image.load(img), (width, height))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.speed = speed
    # Метод прорисовки
    def reset(self):
        window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

# Class for player
class Player(GameObjects):
    def update(self):
        keys = key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_a] and self.rect.x > 5:
            self.rect.x -= self.speed
        if keys[K_d] and self.rect.x < window_width - self.width - 2:
            self.rect.x += self.speed    
        

# Class for balls
class Balls(Player):
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speed
        if self.rect.y > window_height:
            self.rect.x = randint(5, window_width - 85)
            self.rect.y = randint(-200, -50)            

# Making objects
box = Player('box.png', 450, 660, 250, 180, 25)
balls = sprite.Group()
for i in range(2):
    ball = Balls('ball.png', randint(5, window_width - 85), randint(-200, -50), 85, 85, randint(3, 4))
    balls.add(ball)

# Score
score = 0 

# Game cycle
game = True
finish = False
clock = time.Clock()

while game:
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            game = False

    # Displaying sprites
    if finish != True:
        window.blit(background, (0,0))
        box.reset()
        box.update()

        balls.draw(window)
        balls.update()

    # The appearance of balls
    if randint(1, 200) == 1:
        ball = Balls("ball.png", randint(5, window_width - 85),randint(-200, -50), 85, 85, randint(3, 4))
        balls.add(ball)
        display.update()

    # Touching the ball with the platform
    if sprite.spritecollide(box, balls, True):
            ball.remove()
            score += 1
```

That's where the hit should count: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhQIS.jpg
The game itself: https://skr.sh/sKmvhu1YsqS?a

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend customizing the sprite rectangle for the box, so that it only includes the surface (by which I assume you mean the top surface).

```py
class Player(GameObjects):
    def __init__(self, img, x, y, width, height, speed):
        super().__init__(self, img, x, y, width, height, speed)
        self.rect.update(self.rect.left, self.rect.top, self.rect.width, 1)  # <--

    def update(self):
        keys = key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_a] and self.rect.x > 5:
            self.rect.x -= self.speed
        if keys[K_d] and self.rect.x < window_width - self.width - 2:
            self.rect.x += self.speed
```

Additionally, `Balls` should probably not be inheriting from `Player` and should be inheriting from `GameObjects` instead, both for convention and so this new `Player` functionality doesn't apply to balls as well.

Hope this helps!